# What type of Protein ID is this?

Tags: go-enrichment, identifiers

I got a FASTA file from NCBI RefSeq.
These proteins are annotated with IDs like this : protein_id=XP_019970915.1.
What type of ID is this? I would like to have them converted in TrEMBL IDs in order to do, later, a GO term enrichment but I have to know where I am starting from.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but XP_019970915.1 is an 'NCBI Reference Sequence' ID for 'erythrocyte binding antigen-181' (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/XP_019970915.1/). If you look that protein up in UniProt you can find other identifiers/info and GO annotations etc (https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A0A151LVZ9). Does that answer your question?

Comment: In full thanks!